# Cross-compiled Vim on ARM - only colours are bold, & underline

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color

I cross-compiled Vim 9.0 for ARM / arm-linux-gnueabihf
(after also cross-compiling ncurses):

```
# ac_cv_sizeof_int=4 \
vim_cv_getcwd_broken=no \
vim_cv_memmove_handles_overlap=yes \
vim_cv_stat_ignores_slash=yes \
vim_cv_tgetent=zero \
vim_cv_terminfo=yes \
vim_cv_toupper_broken=no \
./configure --build=i586-linux --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-gui --without-x --disable-selinux --disable-acl --disable-gpm  --with-tlib=tinfo  CPPFLAGS=-I../../INSTALL/include/ncurses LDFLAGS=-L../../INSTALL/lib --prefix=/home/blah/tmp/VIM/INSTALL/
```

For testing, I'm ssh'd into an Arm Linux Device - it seems to work as an editor all OK.  But despite it running in a gnome-terminal, with a `$TERM` of `xterm-256color`, after`syntax on`, I only ever seem to still get the default monochrome terminal colouring, with bold and underline highlighting.

The terminal colouring *is* working:

- `tput colors` gives me "256".
- If I run `echo -e "\e[1;34mThis is a blue text.\e[0m"`, I get blue text.

I installed Vim to `/usr/local/...` and it was having problems finding the `share/vim`, until I set `VIMRUNTIME=/usr/local/share/vim/vim90`.

Is it the `vim_cv_tgetent=zero`?  (EDIT: No, removed this)

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be a non-existent set of terminal information files.

I did copy these up from the `ncurses` build, but they were never found in `/usr/local/share`.  Setting the correct `TERMINFO` fixed it.

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/local/share/terminfo
```